# Find .dxf entity based on handle with EZDXF library

Tags: python, autocad, dxf, ezdxf

I've been using the Autocad API to fill out block attributes based on the (pre determined) handle ID. Here is a sample of the implementation:

```
    frame1 = acad.ActiveDocument.HandleToObject('18CA1')
    frame2 = acad.ActiveDocument.HandleToObject('77CE9')

    frames = [frame1, frame2]


    for i in range(len(frames)):
        for attrib in frames[i].GetAttributes():
            if attrib.TagString == 'DATE':
                attrib.TextString = datasource.date
            if attrib.TagString == 'CLIENT_NAME':
                attrib.TextString = datasource.client_name
            attrib.Update()
```

Now I want to implement the same functionality using the ezdxf library. I just haven't been able to find a method similar to *.HandleToObject("xxx")*. Based off the following code I determined that the handle ID's are indeed the same as in the autocad implementation.

```
modelspace = dxf.modelspace()

for e in modelspace:
    if e.dxftype()== 'TEXT':
        print("text: %s\n" % e.dxf.text)
        print("handle: %s\n" % e.dxf.handle)
```

Would this be possible in ezdxf? I have made lists of all the specific handles I need to change and ideally I'd rather iterate over that list than having to iterating over all entities to check their handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*ezdxf* stores all entities of a DXF document in the entity database by their handle as key:

```
doc = ezdxf.new()
msp = doc.modelspace()
p = msp.add_point((0, 0))
```

Retrieve entities by index operator:

```
p1 = doc.entitydb[p.dxf.handle]
assert p1 is p
```

This method raises a `KeyError` if the handle doesn't exist, the `get()` function returns `None` if the handle doesn't exist:

```
p2 = doc.entitydb.get(p.dxf.handle)
assert p2 is p
assert doc.entitydb.get('ABBA') is None
```